# Letting custom view to move only downwards

Tags: android, user-interface, imageview

Im using the following code to let users move imageview. I have created a custom imageview for the same.

```
public class MovableImageView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView implements ImageView.OnTouchListener{

    float x,y =0;
    private static final String TAG = MovableImageView.class.getSimpleName();

    public MovableImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setOnTouchListener(this);

    }

    public MovableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    public MovableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        setOnTouchListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {


            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                x = this.getX() - event.getRawX();
                y = this.getY() - event.getRawY();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                this.animate()
                        .x(event.getRawX() + x)
                        .y(event.getRawY() + y)
                        .setDuration(0)
                        .start();
                Log.e("pos","x:"+String.valueOf(event.getRawX() + x)+"y:"+String.valueOf(event.getRawX() + y));

                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Im using the above code to let the user drag the imageview. This code works. However it also allows the user to move the image towards the left and right.
Im trying to make it move only towards the bottom and not upwards or left or towards the right. May  I know how can I be able to sort this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class MovableImageView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView implements ImageView.OnTouchListener{

    float y =0;
    private static final String TAG = MovableImageView.class.getSimpleName();

    public MovableImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setOnTouchListener(this);

    }

    public MovableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    public MovableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        setOnTouchListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {


            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                y = this.getY() - event.getRawY();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                if (this.getY() < event.getRawY() + y) { //checks if the new position is greater (means going down) to the current position
                   this.animate()
                        .y(event.getRawY() + y)
                        .setDuration(0)
                        .start();
                   Log.e("pos","y:"+String.valueOf(event.getRawY() + y));
                }
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Basically, I just removed all your `x-axis` code so only the `y-axis` (the vertical one) will be used.

**Updated:**
Locks swiping up

Comment: works fine... however is it possible to prevent moving upwards?

Comment: You mean there's no way to go upwards? Once he swipe it downward, there's no option to return it right?

Comment: wait, let me try the code, ill fix it so it just goes down.

Comment: Updated my answer, I've also tried and tested it. It works.